# Whats faster? Copy via nfs-mount or via scp?

Tags: linux, unix, scp, mount, nfs

we have a network of several machines and we want to distribute a big directory (ca. 10 GB) to every box.

It is located on an nfs-server and is mounted on all machines, so first approach is to just use normal `cp` to copy the files from the mounted to a local directory. This is easy, but unfortunately there is no progress bar, because it is not intended to use it for network copies (or is it?).

Using `scp` is intended for copying across network, but it may encrypt everything and therefore be slow.

Should one be faster, and if so, which: `cp` on nfs-mount or `scp`?

Comment: If you have a lot of destination machines, perhaps making a compressed archive (e.g. with `tar czf`) and transferring it might be faster (then de-archive on each destination machine).

Comment: Also, if the folder contains lots of files, scp might be slower than desirable. I suggest then doing `tar c /your/folder | ssh user@remoteMachine cd /destination/folder \; tar x`. This will pass all files as a single tar without compression (you can add it if you want) and extract them at the receiving point. But I'm sorry I don't know if this will be faster or not than a simple `cp` over nfs.

Comment: Also, probably this belongs to superuser.SE or serverfault.SE rather than to SO

Comment: Use Carlos approach (NFS is almost evil, if only for the way it messes up security). You can add a '| pv .....' before the '|ssh ...' to have a nice progress bar. Usually we write it as :  `tar cf - /your/folder | pv | ssh user@remoteMachine "cd /destination/folder ; tar xf -"`   to clearly show that it uses standard output/input (-)

Comment: I didn't know about `pv`. Very nice :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use `rsync`, it can show you the progress (with `--progress` option) and is more lightweight than `scp`.

You can enable compression manually with `-z`.

Comment: That depends on the definition of "lightweight".

Comment: if you use an rsync daemon on the far side it's much lighter than scp, but most people end up using the ssh/scp based mechanism

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer OP that which is faster between cp on nfs-mount or scp.

Comment: @DurgeshSuthar not literally, but apparently it solved the OP's problem.